# How to set data (Qt::UserRole) into QSqlQueryModel column?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QSqlQueryModel that handling data , im trying to set Qt::UserRole to column
but i can’t figure a way to do it i have implement the data method :
basically what i want is to hide the Qt::DisplayRole of ndex.column() 4 and set it to Qt::UserRole

```
   QVariant MyListSqlModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        QVariant value = QSqlQueryModel::data(index, role);
     QVariant valueEmpty = "";
      int j = index.column();
        if (value.isValid() && role == Qt::DisplayRole && j== 4 )
     {

      QModelIndex LinkIndex = QSqlQueryModel::index(index.row(),4);
      setData(LinkIndex,value,Qt::UserRole); // this is not working and gives me erorr


      return valueEmpty;
     }
     else
     {
       return value;
     }
    }
```

it give me this error that i know what it is the implement method is not const

```
error C2662: 'MyListSqlModel::setData' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyListSqlModel' to 'MyListSqlModel&'
```

but what is the right way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want _set_ data in data _getter_?

Comment: in the getter im getting the Text of the Qt::DisplayRole
and i want to clear it from the Qt::DisplayRole , and set it into the setData

Comment: Why not return data for `Qt::UserRole` simply insted of `Qt::DisplayRole`? your `data` is `const` function, and one would expect, that it doesn't change model.

Comment: how can i set the UserRole of this item ?

Comment: you can return `data(Qt::UserRole)` if `role==Qt::DisplayRole` and `column==4`

Comment: i need just to set the value of the DisplayRole to the UserRole
not return empty value ( from the UserRole)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from the code you want to ignore the `Qt::DisplayRole` of the column 4. In that case you don't have to deal with the `UserRole` but just return empty `QVariant`

```
QVariant MyListSqlModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
   if(index.column() == 4 && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
          return QVariant();

   //else process the data in ususal way
}
```

Please correct me if I misunderstood the question

**edit**

Thanks for the comment. I have started myself using custom roles for my models. The workflow goes like this:

> Define a custom user role in the header

```
enum MyDataRoles {
   MyDisplayRole = Qt::UserRole + 10
}
```

> Now for the `setData` I am using a snippet from [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-querymodel-editablesqlmodel-cpp.html).
>
> And for getting the data you can use snippet from [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/sql-querymodel-customsqlmodel-cpp.html). You just have to check for the `MyDisplayRole`

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank , but i know this part . the thing is that i have also itemDelegate and in its paint method i like to get the string that used to be in the Qt::DisplayRole . so i like to set it into the UserRole

Comment: hi,i know the examples very well . this is not what im looking for
i found some open source project that looks like doing what im want
see here :http://wally.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.3.1/history_8cpp-source.html , search for PhotosQueryModel::data( 
but i don't manage to make it work , basically they setting widget with QLabel into the column